# How to determine if User is external

Tags: permissions, soap, user, owd

I want to know which sharing rules ([OWD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_owd_external.htm)) are relevant for each user.
In order to do that, I need to know if user is internal or external.
How can i get this info using SOAP API?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UserType field on User, see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm#profilelicensetype):

> The category of user license. Each UserType is associated with one or
>   more UserLicense records. Each UserLicense is associated with one or
>   more profiles. In API version 10.0 and later, valid values include:
>
> - Standard: user license. This user type also includes Salesforce Platform and Salesforce Platform One user licenses. Label is Standard.
> - PowerPartner: User whose access is limited because he or she is a partner and typically accesses the application through a partner
>     portal or community. Label is Partner.
> - CSPLitePortal: user whose access is limited because he or she is an    organization's customer and accesses the application through
>     aCustomer Portal or community. Label is High Volume Portal.
> - CustomerSuccess: user whose access is limited because he or she is an    organization's customer and accesses the application through a
>     Customer Portal. Label is Customer Portal User.
> - PowerCustomerSuccess:    user whose access is limited because he or she is an organization's    customer and accesses the application
>     through a Customer Portal.    Label is Customer Portal Manager. Users
>     with this license type can    view and edit data they directly own or
>     data owned by or shared with    users below them in the Customer
>     Portal role hierarchy.
> - CsnOnly: user whose access to the application is limited to Chatter.    This user type includes Chatter Free and Chatter moderator
>     users.    Label is Chatter Free.

Comment: So, which of these indicate an external user? Are you sure that's the right field?

Comment: PowerPartner, CSPLitePortal, CustomerSuccess, PowerCustomerSuccess are all kinds of portal users. 

Standard and CsnOnly are internal users.

I'm pretty sure that's right - that's what I've used in my projects. In my cases, it was a simple Community, and external users were only CSPLitePortal.